# PrimeNg: Accordian tabs not closing automatically

Tags: angular, angular6, primeng

I am using PrimeNg in an Angular 6 application. I am attempting to upgrade PrimeNg from v4.2.1 to v6.1.7.

The HTML is like follows:

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="tab1">.....</p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="tab2">.....</p-accordionTab>
    <customComp1></customComp1>
    <customComp2></customComp2>
</p-accordion>
```

Both `customComp1` and `customComp2` are something like this:

```
<p-accordionTab header="tabX">.....</p-accordionTab>
```

The `p-accordian` is configured such that only one tab can be open at one time.

The final DOM on inspecting in browser looks like this:

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="tab1">.....</p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="tab2">.....</p-accordionTab>
    <customComp1>
        <p-accordionTab header="tab3">.....</p-accordionTab>
    </customComp1>
    <customComp2>
        <p-accordionTab header="tab4">.....</p-accordionTab>
    </customComp2>
</p-accordion>
```

**The Issue:** This works fine when I open `tab1` or `tab2` and then attempt to open the other, but when I open `tab3` and/or `tab4`, any other open tab does not close automatically, so I can see multiple open tabs.

**I am looking for** a way to link all the tabs together so that they all know they belong to the same parent accordion.

This was **working as expected in v4.2.1** but so far I have tested it with **v6.0.0 and v6.1.7 and it doesn't work as expected**.

**Secondly**, I cannot see the toggle arrows that accompany p-accordionTabs either. Any help on that front is appreciated too!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do:

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="tab1">.....</p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="tab2">.....</p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="tab3"><customComp1>....</customComp1></p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="tab4"><customComp2>....</customComp2></p-accordionTab>

</p-accordion>
```

Comment: I do not want to reverse the DOM like you suggested, because that will be a major change as `customComp`s are being used in multiple places and are in themselves involved elements. But yea, last resort. What bugs me is that it was working in v4 and I wonder if some config will make it work in v6 too.